# Action as the integral of a differential form

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, action

I'm wondering if the action functional can be written as the integral of a differential form and if so how it relates to the Lagrangian. I tried considering in 1D the Lagrangian $L(q,v,t)$ as a function on the tangent bundle of configuration space and time, $L:T\mathcal M\times\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$,
which can be evaluated on a curve $\gamma:[a,b]\to T\mathcal M\times\mathbb R$ parameterized as $\gamma(t) = (q_\gamma(t),v_\gamma(t),t)$ so that the action of the curve is
$$\mathcal S[\gamma] = \int_a^b L(\gamma(t))\mathrm dt$$
Expressed as an integral of a 1-form $s = s_q\mathrm dq + s_v\mathrm dv + s_t\mathrm dt$  the action would look like this
$$\mathcal S[\gamma] = \int_\gamma s$$
Then if this is written as the integral over $t$ using the velocity vector $\dot\gamma = (\dot q_\gamma, \dot v_\gamma, 1)$,
$$\mathcal S[\gamma] = \int_a^b s(\dot\gamma(t))\mathrm dt$$
I see that "action form" should be identified with the Lagrangian as $s(\dot\gamma) = L(\gamma)$. However I don't think it's possible to "remove" $\gamma$ to get the $s_q, s_v, s_t$ as functions of $T\mathcal M\times\mathbb R$ in terms of the Lagrangian since this relation involves the time derivatives explicitly:
$$s_q(\gamma)\dot q_\gamma + s_v(\gamma)\dot v_\gamma + s_t(\gamma) = L(\gamma)$$
So I don't think this is the right approach. I tried researching this and I found [this paper](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/mp_arc/c/20/20-106.pdf)$^1$ which seems to define the action as the integral of the Lagrangian times the volume form $S = \int_{\mathcal M}L\star 1$, which I interpret to mean the action form is $s = L\mathrm dq\wedge\mathrm dv\wedge\mathrm dt$. The problem is I don't understand how this can give the action of a curve since it must be integrated over a volume rather than a curve. Other than that I haven't found anything conclusive, so any help or pointers would be appreciated. Thanks

1. Extremised Action Functionals On Manifolds, Jethro Linley

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. For what it's worth, for a $n$-dimensional field theory one defines a Lagrangian $n$-form $$\mathbb{L}~=~{\cal L}~\mathrm{d}x^0\wedge\ldots \wedge\mathrm{d}x^{n-1},$$ where ${\cal L}$ is the Lagrangian density.
2. In point mechanics we have $n=1$, so it is a Lagrangian $1$-form $$\mathbb{L}~=~L~\mathrm{d}t,$$ where $L$ is the Lagrangian.
3. The action then becomes $S~=~\int \mathbb{L}$.

Comment: Ahhh that's it, $s_q\mathrm dq + s_v\mathrm dv + s_t\mathrm dt = L\mathrm dt$ so $s_q = 0$, $s_v = 0$, $s_t = L$. It seems so obvious now that you point it out, but I think it's because I was originally considering time independent Lagrangians on just $T\mathcal M$ that I didn't consider $\mathrm dt$ as a "proper" differential form. Thanks a lot.